# HTML5 Canvas object oriented

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hi im trying to create a stock bar chart using html5 canvas, first I've decided to create bar object with different methods but can't make it work. Generated bar object does not appears

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1024" height="600" style="border:3px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var context = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");


function Bar(time,open,high,low,close,dir){
    vertcord=time
    openC=open
    highC=high
    lowC=low
    closeC=close
    line_width=8
    bar_col='#ff0000'

    if (dir==1){
    bar_col='#ace600'
    }

    this.moveTo(vertcord,highC);
    this.lineTo(vertcord,lowC);
    this.moveTo(vertcord-line_width/2,closeC);
    this.lineTo(vertcord+30,closeC);
    this.lineWidth = line_width
    this.strokeStyle = bar_col;
    this.stroke();


}

for (i=0; i < 300; i++) {
    tempShape = new Bar(450+i,0,200,100,150,1);
    tempShape.drawToContext(context);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need the [rendering context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) of the canvas instead of `this` in the constructor function.

Comment: Bar.drawToContext() is not even defined, is it?

Comment: But Bar should be an object i will improve it later by other functions etc.

Comment: You need to create that method before you can call it, otherwise an error occurs, and the execution will be stopped. About the OOP, you're overriding the newly-created object on every round of the loop, hence using an object is a bit overkilling here. I understand you're taking the first steps with OOP in JS, maybe it would be a good idea to take [a short tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function Bar(time,open,high,low,close,dir){
    this.vertcord = time;
    this.openC = open;
    this.highC = high;
    this.lowC = low;
    this.closeC = close;
    this.line_width = 8;
    this.bar_col = '#ff0000';

    if (dir ==1 ) {
     this.bar_col = '#ace600';
    }
  
    this.drawToContext = function(ctx) { 
 ctx.moveTo(this.vertcord, this.highC);
   ctx.lineTo(this.vertcord, this.lowC);
    ctx.moveTo(this.vertcord-this.line_width/2,this.closeC);
     ctx.lineTo(this.vertcord+30,this.closeC);
     ctx.lineWidth = this.line_width
     ctx.strokeStyle = this.bar_col;
     ctx.stroke();
    }
}

var context = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");

for (i=0; i < 300; i++) {
    tempShape = new Bar(450+i,0,200,100,150,1);
    tempShape.drawToContext(context);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1024" height="600" style="border:3px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

I think this is how it supposed to be.You better read [a tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS) how to properly implement an object oriented pattern in JavaScript. And learn what "this" means in JavaScript.

Comment: Several days trying to make independent color to each object, no progress even if i make objects jwithout loop just  tempShape1, tempShape2 and then try to change the color of the particular shape for example tempShape1.bar_col='#ace600' it will change color for all the shapes. I cant understand why it happens because other parameters of the shape: cordinates, variables etc works fine. There is no problem to change positions and form